# Custom file Copier with bash scripting

Tags: bash

I wrote these lines of code to copy a file provided by the user into a directory... but the conditional section keeps raising bugs...

Here is the code:

```
 echo Enter filename to copy: 
 read files
 echo
 echo Enter Directory to copy files to: 
 read dir
 echo 
 echo copying file $files to $dir directory

 #check if file exists 
 if [ ! -e "$files" ] then 
     echo file does not exist
     exit 0
 else
    if [ ! -d "$dir" ]; then #check if dir exists
        mkdir ~$dir 
        echo ~$dir 
        cp $files $dir 
        ls $dir
    fi 
 fi
```

Expected behaviour: The file provided as argv should be copied to the provided directory, if the directory does not exist, it should be created. If the file does not exist then exit the script with the message that the file does not exist.

Actual behaviour: `syntax error near unexpected token 'else'`

[image: actual behaviour]

Comment: Copy paste your script to [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and see what happens. It should help you fix it

Comment: (Clue): it is one of your if-conditions, compare them both to see if they are written right

Comment: Besides the syntax error in the if-statement, remove the `~` in `~$dir` (or test/create/cp/ls with `~/$dir`) and consider complicated input (filenames with spaces, directories with subdirs or relative paths).

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `;` in the first `if` statement. It should be:

```
if [ ! -e "$files" ]; then
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the syntax error in your if-statement, the script will fail if you pass more than one file. A possible solution is to rewrite the script as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo Enter filename to copy:                                                   
read files                                                                     
echo                                                                           
echo Enter Directory to copy files to:                                         
read dir                                                                       
echo                                                                           
echo copying file\(s\) $files to $dir directory                                

#check if file exists                                                          
for file in $files; do                                                          
     if [ ! -e "$file" ]; then                                                  
         echo file does not exist                                               
         exit 0                                                                 
     else                                                                       
        if [ ! -d "$dir" ]; then #check if dir exists                           
            mkdir $dir                                                          
            echo $dir                                                           
        fi                                                                      
        cp "$file" "$dir"                                                       
     fi                                                                         
 done                                                                           
 ls $dir
```

Sample call:

```
./scriptname *txt
```

This will copy all your text files into the specified directory.

Comment: This worked better for me. It was closer to what I needed... But if I passed in the path to the file, then it wouldn't copy. 

`Documents/Apps/Books/README.md` 

This would raise error saying that the file does not exist... How do I handle this execption???

Comment: Humm, it works for me. The script will prompt the user for a file name `Enter filename to copy`. Make sure you write the complete path to the file. For example if I write: `/home/user/Documents/Apps/Books/README.md` the file will get copied, but if I type incomplete path: `Documents/Apps/Books/README.md` file won't be copied.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #!/bin/bash
 echo Enter filename to copy:
 read files
 echo
 echo Enter Directory to copy files to:
 read dir
 echo 
 echo copying file $files to $dir directory

 #check if file exists 
 if [ ! -e $files ]; then  #Missing ; and remove ""
     echo file does not exist
     exit 0
 elif [ ! -d $dir ]; then #check if dir exists
        mkdir -p ~$dir  #-p for recursive folder path
        echo ~$dir 
 fi
 cp $files $dir  #can mention -vf to force copy and verbose
 ls $dir
```

Comment: If a put the file path it wouldn't copy. `urs/lib/share/file.txt` Why is this occurring? @Thirushetty

Comment: Yes. It says file does not exist

Comment: Oh, its problem of your file path, try like `./script.sh /path/to/file`